# Technical problem: Suddenly I cannot leave comments

Tags: support, comment

When I click on "leave a comment", even on my own questions, I get sent to the the top of the page/post. I also can't seem to leave additional answers. Any idea what is going on? I don't think I changed any settings on my computer. Is there an Explorer setting that could be doing this?

Comment: What happens if you try another web browser?

Comment: Operating system? Browser used? Any browser add-ons you installed? Have you tried other web browsers? Have you tried using a blank profile? It sounds like a software problem: the "leave a comment"  link is a JavaScript link, and the behaviour you saw is consistent with what could happen if you browsed the page on a browser that doesn't support javascript. This leads me to conclude that this is possibly a software problem on your computer. So please include those details so others can help you resolve it.

Comment: @WillieWong Thanks, for some reason I can now leave comments?! It seems like when my computer is docked at my office workstation it is fine, but when I browse from the laptop it wasnt working. Ill see if it still happens when I undock my laptop. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me in Google Chrome as well. You will see a little icon in your URL bar that says "This page includes scripts from unauthenticated sources." I did  have to click that icon, plus clear my cache. Most likely you will have to do something similar in your browser.